# Flip object in Blender. Is it possible?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I would like to simply flip the highlighted pedal to make it look opposite to the other one.
Is it possible in Blender?   The object is not mirrored it is just a duplicate fo the first one.

[image]

Comment: just press S X -1

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Ctrl + M to mirror would also help

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and then select a mirror axis.